# Python: How can I write a text file that pulls data from an excel file. Format as “Column header: Cell Value)

Tags: python, excel, text, format, openpyxl

I am trying to automate an output for an excel file so it is more easily readable. I have an excel file with columns A through BY. My plan is to read each row with a date that matches user input. Then read each cell in the row and if the cell is not blank, output the cell value. After this, the data will be written to a text file in the format:

---

- Name
- Column header C: cell Value
- Column header K: cell value
- Column header Z: Cell Value

---

- Name 2
- Column header C: cell value
- etc.

---

“Name” is one of the columns. So I think the idea would be to make a dictionary of names with each name having a nested dictionary of each column header and the value.

I am using openpyxl to complete this task. I am able to properly loop through all of the rows and cells that match my criteria. However I am having trouble converting this to a text file in the format that I am interested in using. **Can anyone provide some methods of printing the cell values and the accompanying column header using a for loop for all the columns? As well as in the desired format?** Happy to provide any more information that is needed. Thanks to anyone that can help! This is also my first post so let me know how else I can help.

EDIT: I added some of the code I used to loop through the columns and rows. "work date" is a user input value that chooses only rows with the correct date value we want to work with.

Go through each row of given date and print cells with value in them

```
cards = {}
activity_list = []
for row in active_sheet.iter_rows(max_row=22):
    if row[0].value == work_date:
        cards[row[1].value] = ['Start']
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value:
                activity_list.append(cell.value)
                for key, value in cards.items():
                    cards[key].append(activity_list)
    else:
        continue
```

Here we select only rows with correct date and print only relevant, non-empty cells. And they are printed and formatted to a txt file.

```
with open(timecardtxt, 'w') as file_object:
    for key, values in cards.items():
        file_object.write("Name: " + key)
        for item in value[1]:
            print(item, file=file_object)
```

Comment: You've selected `openpyxl` as a package to access the files (OK choice, should meet your needs), but have you written any code so far? Please share what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: In my experience, I have had this issue when I was new. But after doing data manipulations for some time I came to know this method is not efficient. And my seniors told me the same. If you have time, then I suggest go for pandas. In pandas you can convert excel like file to pandas dataframe(it will act like an object in memory). 
Then you can manipulate that object like dictionary. For small data in MBs its good. But for GBs and TBs. There are other methods like map reduce and other libraries to help.

Comment: @Grismar I have added some code, thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @ShikharVerma Thank you for taking the time to help. I am decently familiar with R so I think I could get a hold of pandas pretty quickly. Thank you for letting me know that my method is inefficient, I was definitely struggling to figure out how to piece everything together.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a number of errors that I don't think need too much discussion here, but it's clear it won't run as presented, or do what you say you need.

However, I think this is really all you need:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Note that you can install `pandas` with `pip install pandas` and that `pandas` requires `openpyxl` to be installed for `read_excel` to work.

This simple example doesn't do any filtering or anything, but that's easy using the dataframe `df`. And empty cells are just represented as nothing in a .csv anyway.